# ¿Cómo contar el total de registros teniendo tablas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema al no saber mucho de SQL.
resulta que tengo las tablas:
"reservation", que trae los siguientes datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la tabla: "status":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De eso necesito contar la cantidad de registros, agrupándolos por los nombres de la tabla "status". Ejemplo:
El estado Pendiente trae 3 registros y debería mostrar los otros estados con un 0, si corresponde.
He usado COUNT, pero no me da el resultado que deseo.

Este es mi consulta realizada

```
SELECT status.name, COUNT(*) AS cantidadreservas FROM  status, reservation WHERE reservation.status_id = "1, 2, 3, 4" GROUP BY status.name
```

Siendo este el resultado que entrega:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿me podrían orientar como se hacen este tipo de consultas?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Pablo, bievenido! ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la consulta que has realizado? PD: Es probable que solamente te falte agregar [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: @Marcos Hola, si uso group by, alli edite mostrando la consulta con el resultado que me entrega. Lamento si mi consulta es demasiado bestia, todavia soy muy inexperto en esto.

Comment: Además de faltar tu condición de JOIN, si `status_id` es númerico, nunca será igual a la cadena `"1, 2, 3, 4"`. ¿No querrías usar el operador [`in()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu consulta únicamente le falta el criterio de combinación de tablas, que has confundido con los distintos valores de agrupamiento:

```
SELECT status.name, COUNT(*) AS cantidadreservas
  FROM  status, reservation
  WHERE reservation.status_id = "1, 2, 3, 4"  -- --> Aquí está el error
  GROUP BY status.name;
```

Y debería ser:

```
SELECT status.name, COUNT(*) AS cantidadreservas
  FROM  status, reservation
  WHERE reservation.status_id = status.id
  GROUP BY status.name;
```

Aunque también se puede hacer así:

```
SELECT status.name, COUNT(*) cantidadreservas
  FROM  status JOIN reservation
  ON reservation.status_id = status.id
  GROUP BY 1;
```

O, en MySQL, incluso así:

```
SELECT * FROM status JOIN (
    SELECT status_id id, COUNT(*) cantidadreservas
      FROM  reservation
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues basicamente, no le estas diciendo como unir las tablas...

Tu query, no le dice al motor que tiene que hacer.. le tira las cosas para que decida.. y decide bien, pero obviamente no es lo que queres...

vos queres que cuente la cantidad de registros segun el estado... Lo del nombre, es anecdotico....

Tu query, podria ser asi:

```
SELECT reservation.status_id, COUNT(*) AS cantidadreservas 
FROM  reservation 
WHERE reservation.status_id = "1, 2, 3, 4" 
GROUP BY reservation.status_id
```

Ahora, si vos queres tambien el nombre, tenes dos opciones... una de ellas es hacer un query sobre este query, que agregue el nombre.. otra, es hacer lo que trataste de hacer, pero con un JOIN... y usandolo como corresponde...